# Errors Model State Chamada Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde, tenho uma tela de cadastro que estou fazendo uma chamada ajax para enviar os dados, contudo quando o usuário não preenche algum campo preciso mostrar uma mensagem de erro de validação de campo. Em outras telas de cadastro do meu sistema eu utilizei o  @Html.ValidationMessageFor para informar erro de validação contudo nesse caso não funciona pois não estou fazendo o post dentro do Html.BeginForm. Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como eu poderia mostrar uma mensagem de erro de validação no padrão do Html.BeginForm sem usar Html.BeginForm?

```js
 $.ajax({
            url: '/Teste/Save',
            data: JSON.stringify(salesmain),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: true,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                else 
                {
                   
               
                    document.getElementById("btnsalvar").disabled = false; 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Neste caso você possui um `Model` contendo as propriedades de validações (assim como se faz no `Html.BeginForm()` comum) ou é um formulário "seco"?

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira  Possui um Model com as propriedades de validação no parão que se usa o Html.BeginForm().

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão: Já que você está postando utilizando Ajax e possui um `Model` com propriedades e validações, você pode continuar fazendo a validação no lado do servidor, mas recarregando apenas o formulário.

**Primeiro passo: Transformar seu formulário em um `PartialView`**

Chamarei ela de "_MinhaPartialView". Exemplo:

```
//Não colocar funções javascript aqui, elas não funcionam em PartialViews, mova-as para a tela principal.
@model MeuModel;
<form>
    @Html.TextboxFor(x=>x.Codigo)
</form>
```

E na sua tela principal, renderizar o PartialView:

```
<div id="divPrincipal">
     @Html.Partial("_MinhaPartialView", Model)
</div>
```

**Segundo passo: Fazer seu `Controller` retornar a `PartialView` em caso de falha na validação**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MeuModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        return Json(new {success = true});
    }

    return PartialView("_MinhaPartialView", model);
}
```

Assim, em caso de sucesso, o formulário irá retornar um `json` contendo a indicação de que houve sucesso. Em caso de falha de validação do model, irá retornar um `html` contendo o formulário inteiro, incluindo as mensagens de validação.

**Terceiro passo: Renderizar o retorno da sua função Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Teste/Save',
        data: JSON.stringify(salesmain),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        //dataType: 'json', <-- REMOVER ESTA LINHA, AGORA A FUNÇÃO RETORNA JSON E HTML
        autoUpload: true,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                location.reload();
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById('#divPrincipal').innerHTML = result;
                //Alternativa caso você use jQuery: $("#divPrincipal").html(result);
            }
        }
    });
```

Desta forma a `divPrincipal` vai substituir seu form atual, sem validação, por um novo form contendo as validações e as mensagens de erro sem recarregar a página. E caso retorne um JSon indicando sucesso, irá recarregar a página inteira.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei um artigo que explica como fazer. Testei e funcionou, segue o link:
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216439/Data-Validation-Using-Annotations-for-jQuery-Ajax